# How to use Apache POI to read spreadsheets with Google App Engine?

Tags: java, excel, google-app-engine, apache-poi, jxl

I've been using [JXL](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) for a while to process excel files from inside the webapp folder. This works in both development and production. I just inject a `ServletContext` and call something like:

`Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(servletContext.getRealPath("WEB-INF/myfile.xls")))` and JXL can read the file and process it.

I recently switched to using [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/index.html) in an App Engine Servlet but I get an exception:

```
[ERROR] java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\Users\Drew\IntelliJ\UsavApp\target\UsavAppV7-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\myfile.xlsx" "write")
[ERROR]     at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)
[ERROR]     at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
[ERROR]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:429)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkWrite(SecurityManager.java:979)
[ERROR]     at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:229)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.poi.poifs.nio.FileBackedDataSource.newSrcFile(FileBackedDataSource.java:130)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.poi.poifs.nio.FileBackedDataSource.<init>(FileBackedDataSource.java:46)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.<init>(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:218)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.<init>(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:166)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:278)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:250)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:229)
[ERROR]     at com.utilitiessavings.usavappv7.server.handler.parse.ParseElecTariffBooksHandler.processTariffsFromExcel(ParseElecTariffBooksHandler.java:108)
[ERROR]     at com.utilitiessavings.usavappv7.server.handler.parse.ParseElecTariffBooksHandler.execute(ParseElecTariffBooksHandler.java:91)
[ERROR]     at com.utilitiessavings.usavappv7.server.handler.parse.ParseElecTariffBooksHandler.execute(ParseElecTariffBooksHandler.java:39)
...etc
```

From reading around I gather POI isn't totally compatible with GAE, but most people talk about creating files from scratch, or writing them to the local disk. I'm not doing either of those so I wanted to be sure this is a limitation of App Engine and not something I'm doing.

My guess from the exception would be that POI needs write access even to read the file, whereas JXL didn't. **Is there a way to read a spreadsheet in app engine using Apache POI?**

Comment: Open the file in read-only mode, rather than read-write (default)?

Comment: I didn't see that in the Javadocs before. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer - in a case like this you should explicitly tell Apache POI to open your file in read-only mode

For a `.xlsx` file, do that with

```
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(new File("input.xlsx"), PackageAccess.READ);
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
```

For a `.xls` file, do that with

```
NPOIFSFileSystem fs = new NPOIFSFileSystem(new File("input.xls"), true);
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
```

If you're using `WorkbookFactory`, then you can do that by passing in `null` for the password and [setting the read-only flag](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html#create%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) with

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("input.xlsx"), null, true);
```

In general, reading from an `InputStream` is always read-only, it's with Files where there's an option for read-only vs read-write

See the [constructor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/OPCPackage.html#open%28java.lang.String,%20org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageAccess%29) [javadocs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/NPOIFSFileSystem.html#NPOIFSFileSystem%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) for a little bit more details, and the [WorkbookFactory](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html#create%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) one too.

Comment: I've actually been using `WorkbookFactory` to open the file. There is a constructor here that works if you pass null and true as the second and third parameters: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html#create(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean)

Comment: Strange though - I'm getting `OutOfMemoryError`s saying the heap space has been exceeded. It's fine on the development server, but in production it fails either reading from the file or an inputstream. All files under 5MB so confusing!